# Is it possible to play an swf8 resource in swf10 environment in OpenLaszlo?

Tags: swfobject, openlaszlo, lzx

I know that its not possible to play a swf 8 resource in swf10. But is there any workaround for this?
I want to change the frame value of one resource by using

```
this.viewname.setAttribute('frame',3).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Another option would be to extract the resource, if you just want to display an image, using tools like http://www.swftools.org/

Comment: Why did you use tag this question [tag:swfobject]? Do you use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your SWF into the HTML page?

Comment: @RajuBitter: I use the lz.embed to embed the laszlo swf and swfobject to embed a flex compiled swf. I was trying that in both the platforms.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. How was the SWF8 generated initially? Flash authoring tool (FLA)?

Comment: @RajuBitter: Yes, intially it was developed by another team and right now we don't have the .fla files with us. I think i have to look into the ffmpeg option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SWF file is a pure SWF movie then it has an AVM codec which you can't play in Flash 9+, but you can re-encode it to AVM2 which will work in Flash 9+ with a video conversion tool like FFMPEG (http://ffmpeg.org/) with a command similar to the following:

```
ffmpeg -i mysfw8file.swf -f avm2 myswf10file.swf
```

(This assumes that you have a recent version of FFMPEG that supports the AVM2 codec).

Note: That if your SWF8 is an application then it will have unpredictable results since OpenLaszlo views were never intended to load SWF applications, only SWF movies.